# How to make images go inline vs break to a new line?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/KuFbH/

I am trying to get these 4 images to all be displayed in one line without breaking to the next line. For some reason I can't get it to work although if I zoom out on the page it appears exactly how I want it. What can I do?

I want to be able to scroll horizontally to view them.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="scroll">
        <div class="Wrapper">   
            <div class="scrollArea">
             <img src="">
             <img src="">
             <img src="">
             <img src="">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{  
    font-size:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
} 

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main{
    position: absolute; 
    top:100px; 
    bottom:100px; 
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

#scroll{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.Wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.scrollArea{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.scrollArea img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
 var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.scrollArea img').each(function(){
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });

    $('.scrollArea').css("width", totalWidth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images wrap because that's the default behavior for inline elements. If you don't want them to wrap, specify the appropriate behavior on the parent element:

```
.scrollArea {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.Wrapper {white-space:nowrap;}
```

demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FEb9L/

Answer (score 0):

Set your image to `display: inline-block;` in your css stylesheet.